# DB strange behaviour

Tags: database, oracle, oracle9i

I encountered the following confusing problem:

A DB table was updated through *CSV* file and some *KSH* script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

moduleDir=$ACS_INSTALL/FMC_TER_AM_028/Database
logFile=$moduleDir/install_scripts/`basename $0`_$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M').log

(
  cp -ri $moduleDir/ntscripts/datafiles/* $PROVHOME/database/ntscripts/datafiles
  echo "\n***********************"
  echo "* New/Modified files: *"
  echo "***********************"
  find $moduleDir/ntscripts/datafiles -type f | xargs ls -l
) 2>&1 | tee $logFile

echo "\nInstallation of Database completed\n"
```

The update is equal (under equal I mean that the visual result is the same as the *INSERT* command below) to the following *INSERT* query:

```
INSERT INTO tp_nt_mapping (TARIFF_PLAN, SERVICE_TYPE, NETWORK_TEMPLATE, IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE)
VALUES (171, 'Postpaid', '11', '', '')
```

When I'm using the following *SELECT* command:

```
SELECT * FROM tp_nt_mapping ORDER BY tariff_plan DESC
```

I'm able to see the new inserted record, but when I try with any of the following *SELECT* queries, I'm not:

```
SELECT * FROM tp_nt_mapping WHERE network_template = 11 ORDER BY tariff_plan DESC
SELECT * FROM tp_nt_mapping WHERE network_template = '11' ORDER BY tariff_plan DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: post the table definition and some ksh/sqlplus relevant code.

Comment: probably network_template is char(N) => is left padded with blanks. 11 become '11' wich is different of '   11'. You should use Varchar2.

Comment: Can you show us the results of the query `select dump(tp_nt_mapping) from tp_nt_mapping ORDER BY tariff_plan DESC` ?

Comment: @Florin Ghita: KSH is posted and there are no blanks into the CSV file!

Comment: if the definition of table uses Char type instead of varchar2, blanks would exists in the database. See the definition of your table.

Comment: @A.B.Cade: It returns 93 rows, each and every row is containing the following: Typ=96 Len=13: 116,112,95,110,116,95,109,97,112,112,105,110,103

Comment: @Florin Ghita: TARIFF_PLAN is of type NUMBER, SERVICE_TYPE & NETWORK_TEMPLATE are VARCHAR2(32), IN_CREATE & IN_DELETE are VARCHAR2(8).

Comment: @nenito- sorry, I meant `select dump(network_template) from tp_nt_mapping ORDER BY tariff_plan DESC`

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Now the result is 197 rows with something like that: "Typ=1 Len=3: 49,49,13" - actually the total number of records is 197!

Comment: @A.B.Cade: But there is something strength. Only one row has a "Len=3", all other rows have a "Len=2"!

Comment: The `dump` function shows you what you "really" have in the field. Len is the length in bytes so one row has 3 characters instead of 2. The following numbers are the ascii codes of the chars - 49=1, 13=CR. What do you have when the len is 2 ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: There is always 2-digit number in NETWORK_TEMPLATE column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in `network_template` field isn't just `'11'` but `'11' || chr(13)`.
So you have the `carrige return` char at the end.

You can fix the data by doing:

```
update tp_nt_mapping 
set network_template = replace(network_template, chr(13), '')
```

But better check why it was added on the first place....